# UIPopoverController - SIGABRT when Presented

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I'm attempting to present a popoverView when a barButton is pressed. Unfortunately, the app crashes with the signal SIGABRT every time I try to call it. The "Empty.xib" does have a view designed in it. (As I'm using a barButton, I was unable to use the frame, if you have a workaround for that, please say so too).

```
- (IBAction)loadPopover:(id)sender 
{
    UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIViewController *someVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Empty.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:someVC];

    someView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 372);
    someView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    popoverController.delegate = self;

    self.popoverView = popoverController;

    [self.popoverView presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    // CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[btn frame] fromView:[btn superview]];

    CGRect popoverRect = CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 311);

    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100); 
    [self.popoverView presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Does the crash happen when you reach the last line of your code?

Comment: I don't actually know when the crash happens, I just get the received signal on main.m.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, should've been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions here.

1. Check if the `view`'s outlet is connected
2. Why do you need to allocate a `UIView` like the following? `UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] init];`
3. Check if the sender is of type of `UIBarButtonItem`
4. What is the retain policy for `self.popoverView`? Check if it is `retain` or `strong` (if ARC)
5. Why do you present the popover two times?

Said this, here a simple snippet.

```
UIBarButtonItem* barButton = (UIBarButtonItem*)sender;

UIViewController *someVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Empty" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:someVC];

popoverController.delegate = self;

self.popoverView = popoverController;

[self.popoverView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 200)];

[self.popoverView presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

P.S. Make attention to memory if you don't use ARC.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.xib` part from `initWithNibName:@"Empty.xib"`. Change line to this:

```
UIViewController *someVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Empty" bundle:nil];
```

**Edit:**
From [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) -

> The nib file name should not contain any leading path information.